# window.setTimeout not working in Firefox 18 and IE10 (Chrome and Safari work)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, settimeout, internet-explorer-10, document.write

I have this sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var EventHandler = {};
      EventHandler.writeNumber = function(i){
        document.write(i);
      };      

      for(var i=0; i<100; i++) {
        (function(i) {
          window.setTimeout(function() {
            EventHandler.writeNumber(i);
          },100*i);
        }(i));
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The code writes every second a number on the page. In Chrome 26 and Safari 5 it works fine! In Firefox 18 and IE10 it comes only once (0 is written on the document).

If I change `document.write` to `console.log`, then it works in all browsers. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.write` is supposed to only work once, at the page load.

A page is parsed from the top to the bottom. Every JavaScript found while parsing is executed immediately. When the execution ended or got dispatched (`setTimeout` or any other async stuff) the browser continues parsing.

When you execute `document.write("Test")` the parser will create a text node `Test` directly after the closing `</script>` tag, because it currently is exactly at this postition. If you delay that with a `setTimeout` of 1ms the parser will be at a different point, insertig the text node further down the page.

If you wait too long, the parser will have finished parsing the page and won't accept writes anymore. Or, in case of chrome, the parser tries to fix the programmer's fault and keeps a reference to the position of the `<script>` tag, making it possible to still use `document.write` after the actual parsing has finished.

Use the console and Firebug (`F12`)  to see what happens.

General speaking `document.write` is a very bad practice. It's painfully slow, as the parser has to parse the given string for every kind of HTML element. Use `document.createTextNode` or `document.createElement` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Chrome and Safari (or more precisely in WebKit).  A `document.write` when a page is not in mid-parse implies a `document.open`, and a `document.open` should clear all timeouts per spec.  That's what IE and Firefox do, but WebKit's handling of `document.open` is all sorts of broken.